# Representing collections of set partitions in a relational database

Tags: sql, postgresql, rdbms, set-theory

I have a set of elements. There are various ways I would like to partition the set, in the [mathematical sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set). A partition is defined as a collection of subsets such that every element is in exactly one subset.

I want to represent this situation in a relational database, and I want the relational constraints to enforce the mathematical definition of a partition.

The closest I have gotten is a schema like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE element (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE partition (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE subset (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    partition_id integer REFERENCES partition (id)
);

CREATE TABLE element_subset_mapping (
    element_id integer REFERENCES element (id) NOT NULL,
    partition_id integer REFERENCES partition (id) NOT NULL,
    subset_id integer REFERENCES subset (id) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT uq_element_partition UNIQUE (element_id, partition_id)
);
```

This represents correctly that an element can only occur in one subset for a given partition. But there are at least a couple problems:

- It does not enforce that, within each partition, every element belongs to some subset. I suppose I could take the semantics that a missing (element_id, partition_id) row indicates that the element belongs to a single element subset, but I would prefer to be explicit.
- It does not enforce the requirement that a subset only belongs to one partition. That is, I could have a subset with (id, partition_id) = (22, 37), but still have a element_subset_mapping with (element_id, partition_id, subset_id) = (4005, 42, 22). This should not be allowed because subset 22 belongs to partition 37, not to partition 42.

It feels like there should be a canonical way to do this, but my searches have not yielded any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement that a subset belong to no more than one partition is already being enforced by the primary key constraint on `subset`; however, there is no enforcement that the combination of `subset_id` and `partition_id` in `element_subset_mapping`  reference a corresponding pair in `subset`. The following DDL addresses these issues by making the combination of subset and partition unique in `subset` and combining the foreign keys on `subset_id` and `partition_id` in `element_subset_mapping` into a single foreign key referencing `subset(id, partition_id)`:

```
CREATE TABLE element (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE partition (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE subset (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    partition_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES partition (id),
    CONSTRAINT subset_partition_uq UNIQUE (id, partition_id) 
);

CREATE TABLE element_subset_mapping (
    element_id integer REFERENCES element (id) NOT NULL,
    partition_id integer NOT NULL,
    subset_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT element_subset_mapping_partition_uq UNIQUE (element_id, partition_id),
    CONSTRAINT element_subset_mapping_subset_fk FOREIGN KEY (subset_id, partition_id) REFERENCES subset(id, partition_id)
);
```

The requirement that each element belong to exactly one subset within each partition is a more complex constraint to enforce because it involves rows from multiple tables. Let's begin by creating a trigger function that raises an exception if any elements are missing from any partitions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_all_elements_in_all_partitions() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$FUNC$
  DECLARE
    element_id element.id%TYPE;
    partition_id partition.id%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT e.id, p.id
      INTO element_id, partition_id
      FROM element e
      CROSS JOIN partition p
      LEFT JOIN element_subset_mapping m
        ON e.id = m.element_id
          AND p.id = m.partition_id
      WHERE m.subset_id IS NULL
      LIMIT 1;

    IF element_id IS NOT NULL THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'partition missing element'
        USING DETAIL = FORMAT('Partition (%1$s) is missing element (%2$s).', partition_id, element_id);
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
  END;
$FUNC$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This function can then be used to define constraint triggers on each of the tables that could cause the constraint to be violated: `element`, `partition`, and `element_subset_mapping`.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS all_elements_in_all_partitions ON element;

CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER all_elements_in_all_partitions
  AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON element
  DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE FUNCTION validate_all_elements_in_all_partitions();

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS all_elements_in_all_partitions ON partition;

CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER all_elements_in_all_partitions
  AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON partition
  DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE FUNCTION validate_all_elements_in_all_partitions();

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS all_elements_in_all_partitions ON element_subset_mapping;

CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER all_elements_in_all_partitions
  AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON element_subset_mapping
  DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE FUNCTION validate_all_elements_in_all_partitions();
```

An important aspect of these triggers is that they are `DEFERRED`, which means that they fire when the current transaction is committed instead of as each row or statement is executed. This allows a set of SQL commands to be executed within a transaction to achieve a state that is consistent with the relational requirements.

A requirement that wasn't mentioned in the original post is that all subsets must be non-empty. The following SQL addresses this using the same approach that was used to ensure that all elements are included in every partition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_no_empty_subsets() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$FUNC$
  DECLARE
    partition_id partition.id%TYPE;
    subset_id subset.id%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT s.id, s.partition_id
      INTO subset_id, partition_id
      FROM subset s
      LEFT JOIN element_subset_mapping m
        ON s.id = m.subset_id
      WHERE m.subset_id IS NULL
      LIMIT 1;
      
    IF subset_id IS NOT NULL THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'empty subset'
        USING DETAIL = FORMAT('Subset (%1$s) in partition (%2$s) is empty.', subset_id, partition_id);
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
  END;
$FUNC$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS no_empty_subsets ON subset;

CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER no_empty_subsets
  AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON subset
  DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE FUNCTION validate_no_empty_subsets();

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS no_empty_subsets ON element_subset_mapping;

CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER no_empty_subsets
  AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON element_subset_mapping
  DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE FUNCTION validate_no_empty_subsets();
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you!

Comment: I've revised my answer to address the requirement that subsets be non-empty. I've also added occurrence details to the raised exceptions.